# Converting SRAM to another SRAM

Tags: computer-architecture

How would I convert a 16K x 32 SRAM into a 64K x 8 SRAM?  The 16K x 32 RAM module is a single unit that cannot be altered internally and is capable of address decoding, has tristate outputs, and read/write/and chip enable.  Also only the memory read of the circuit has to be implemented.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "convert"?  Obviously you can't change it: it is what it is.  What kind of solution are you looking for?  And what have you tried?  What research have you done? We expect you to make a significant effort to answer your own question before asking, and to show us in the question what you've tried and what approaches you've considered and rejected.  Finally, is this a question about computer science, or is it a question about electrical engineering?  I'm not quite sure what you are asking, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Hint: use 8 4:1 multiplexers.